# How to convert coloured Captchas to Grey Scale?

Tags: image, imagemagick, captcha

I'm trying to make a capcha solver, but I have ran into some trouble. The captcha that I am trying to solve has different coloured backgrounds.

[image: Captcha One]
[image: Captcha Two]

I need to convert it to black text on white background so that it could easily be recognised by `tesseract-ocr`

I have tried 
`convert *.png -threshold 50% *.png` which only shows some of the digits.

[image] [image]

Comment: The OpenCV tag is unrelated to your ImageMagick question.

Comment: I seem to recall that some questions about solving captchas has been ruled off-topic (perhaps I'm thinking of the ImageMagick forums)

Comment: Yeah, I was indeed recalling something on the ImageMagick forum

Comment: Actually this is for a web scraping project, otherwise I'd have to sit and solve every captcha by hand.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with simple 50% thresholding is that both colours may be lighter than 50% grey and will therefore come out as white. Or, conversely, both colours may be darker than mid-grey and therefore bith come out as black.

You need to do a 2-colour quantisation to get just 2 colours, then go to greyscale and normalize so the lighter colour goes white and the darker one goes black. I am not near a computer, to test, but that should be:

```
convert input.png -colors 2 -colorspace gray -normalize result.png
```

Now, you will find some images are inverted (black on white instead of white on black), so you can either test the top left corner pixel and if it is white, then invert the image. Or, you could get the mean of the image and if it is more than 0.5 that would indicate that the image is largely white and therefore needs inverting.

Invert with:

```
convert input.png -negate output.png
```

Get top-left pixel with:

```
convert image.png -format '%[pixel:p{0,0}]' info:-
```

Get mean value with:

```
convert image.png -format "%[mean]" info:-
```

Comment: I tried `convert input.png -colors 2 -colorspace gray -normalize result.png`  but the outut is still unreadable. https://imgur.com/a/Tstjb

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought esch letter was a separate image - because you have asterisks in your sample code. No, my suggestion won't work if the entire captcha is a single image. I'll have another think.

Comment: Perhaps that is what the person who made the capture intended; to make harder for spammers to break?

Comment: @Bonzo yep they did make it harder, but not impossible